# Как правильно получить значение по ключу в двумерном массиве [ключ, значение]?

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте. Есть некий двумерный массив:

```
Array( [0]=>Array([id]=>1[name]=>Вип) [1]=>Array([id]=>2[name]=>Премиум) )
```

Как будет правильнее получить значение `name`, зная `id`?
Дело в том, что массив может быть очень большой, и данная операция может происходить не один раз: хотелось бы, чтобы это не повлияло на быстродействие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID - уникальный? если да то как нашли break чтобы не прокручивать дальше, а вообще если массив всегда один а поисков много для него то отсортируйте его любым способом (там в дерево запихайте) там поиск в разы быстрее.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, рассказать подробнее о древе? Или ссылоку дайте, где почитать о нём.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, либо хэш функция, добавьте меня в скайп расскажу подробнее Manitikyl

Comment: @Mr_Epic https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

суть в том, что каждая нода имеет максимум две дочерние ноды, левая будет меньше родительской, а правая - больше. Имея на руках корневую ноду, можно легко дойти до нужного места поиска, сравнивая значения искомого числа со значением текущей ноды и идя вправо или влево. Такая организация позволяет сократить путь до искомого элемента от N до log N операций, если память не подводит (рассчитать в таком состоянии не рассчитаю, извините)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то просто пройтись по массиву, сверить id и вывести name.

```
$id = 2;

$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'vip'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'premium')
);

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $return = ($v['id'] == $id) ? $v['name'] : null;
    echo $return;
}
```

Comment: А других вариантов нету, кроме перебора всего массива?

Comment: @Mr_Epic не видел подобного :)

Comment: @Mr_Epic, когда вы подбираетесь к массиву, он для вас выступает в роли черного ящика, есть сколько-то элементов, но неизвестно, что в них. Разве есть еще способы узнать, кроме как заглянуть в каждый? Тут разве что менять сам способ (БД) или вывод (дерево, хэши значений) получения данных.